# Swift - TextView that expands and stays in center

Tags: swift, textview, constraints

I am trying to accomplish an Idea I got in my head but I got stuck..

---

I need a TextView that expands in both ways: widht-height.

That has a minimum and maximum width, and minimum height.

That is centered in the middle of the parent (SCROLL) view.

And that has a button `send` at the bottom trailing part of the view.

**Here's the idea:**

[image]

So if the user types in the box then it expands in both directions. But there's a maximum width for it (so it doesn't go offscreen) but the height is not limited: due to the parent scrollview.

---

**The problem is that the textView's height doesn't expand when text is breaking into new line.**

**Code:**

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    self.adjustTextViewFrames(textView: textView)
}
func adjustTextViewFrames(textView : UITextView){

    var newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))



    if newSize.width > self.view.bounds.width - 20 {
        newSize.width = self.view.bounds.width - (self.view.bounds.width/10)
    }

    messageBubbleTextViewWidthConstraint.constant = newSize.width
    messageBubbleTextViewHeightConstraint.constant = newSize.height

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

}
```

Comment: You seem to only really set the size, you don't really change the `frame.origin.x.`

Comment: The view is centered with constraints on the storyboard

Comment: Why don't you add a height constraint, take an Outlet, edit it's constant

Comment: When calling textView.sizeThatFits() you can't set the width to greatestFiniteMagnitude. You need to set the width to the actual maximum width that you require, which looks like it should be view.bounds.width - 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // let's create our text view
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100)
        textView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        textView.text = "Here is some default text that we want to show and it might be a couple of lines that are word wrapped"

        view.addSubview(textView)

        // use auto layout to set my textview frame...kinda
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        [
            textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
            ].forEach{ $0.isActive = true }

        textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)

        textView.delegate = self
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false

        textViewDidChange(textView)
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print(textView.text)
        let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: .infinity)
        let estimatedSize = textView.sizeThatFits(size)

        textView.constraints.forEach { (constraint) in
            if constraint.firstAttribute == .height {
                constraint.constant = estimatedSize.height
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Credit goes to Brian Voong from Let's Build That App here [link](https://www.letsbuildthatapp.com/course_video?id=2762)